# Java - Huffman tree decoding of a prefix string

Tags: java, string, decode, huffman-code

I'm writing a decode method for my Huffman class that should decode a string of 0's and 1's to find the original message/string. But I can't seem to correctly decode the string.

My decode method:

```
public String decode(String huffString) {
    // TODO: Fill in this method
    int position = 0;
    BinaryTreeNode current = this.root;
    String output = "";

    while(position < huffString.length()){

        if(huffString.charAt(position) == '0'){
            current = current.left;

            if(current.left == null && current.right == null){
                output+= current.getElement();
                current = this.root;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.right;
            if(current.left == null && current.right == null){
                output+= current.getElement();
                current = this.root;  
            }

        }
        position++;



    }
    return output;
}
}
```

I decided to test my code on a simple string of 'a':

> Original string length is 1
>
> Encoded string (length 4), compressed  0.25
>
> 1010
>
> Now we try to reconstruct the original from the encoded string
>
> Oops. There was a problem.  Decoded string is: Letter [letter=a, frequency=6.5336]

The encoding and traversing is correct; the decoding method is off somewhere. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with this line of code:

```
output+= current.getElement();
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: An example of correct output should probably be something like:

> > Enter a string (END to exit) --> Hello there!
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > Now we try to reconstruct the original from the encoded string
> >
> > It worked! String is: hello there

Comment: Might be too late for me, but could you expain what is wrong with the result? Doesn't it say that letter "a" is the result?

Comment: Sure. I probably should have posted the driver as well. I believe the output should return the string as "a", not Letter [letter=a, frequency=6.5336]. So the code is almost there. I'll add an example to my post of what the output might look like for something like "Hello there!".

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem (I think). Your code goes through the input, taking each 0 or 1 separately. Then you try to go down the tree to find the right letter. But if the first level does not contain the right letter, you do not go deeper! Instead, you continue with the next number, and even without resetting to root. You need two nested loops: One per number, and inside one that goes down the tree **until it finds the char**.

Comment: Oh, it is too late... I realize now that my thinking was completely silly, had to remember how Huffman works. Your code looks ok actually, have you tried debugging it yet? I'll have another look later, let us know how it goes.

Comment: I think I figured it out: my BinaryTreeNode is a generic type T and needed to be BinaryTreeNode<Letter> current, so that I could then use output+= current.getElement().getLetter().

Comment: I see, so you appended Letter.toString() to output, instead of just the char.